# Проблема с добавлением рекламы от Unity Ads

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вроде бы все очень просто с *Unity Ads*, скачал плагин, вставил пару строк в код и все, но при тесте в *PlayMode* не показывается реклама, хотя ошибок в коде нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Реклама должна показываться при нажатии на кнопку.

**Код**

```
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

void Start()
{
    Advertisement.Initialize ("ID моего приложения", false);
}

public void ShowAd()
{
    if(Advertisement.IsReady()) 
    Advertisement.Show();
}
```

Comment: Покажите код целиком. А то сейчас у вас методы вне класса. Так не бывает :)

Comment: У вас вообще метод ShowAd вызывается? Вставьте Debug.Log("Ad!") в него и посмотрите появляется ли в консоли текст, когда вы жметё кнопку

Comment: Нашли решение? Если да то расскажите мне пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно включить рекламу в приложении в окне Services рядом с вкладкой Inspector, если такого окна нет, то просто включите его: Window => General => Services или сочетанием клавиш Ctrl + 0.